# jQuery Setting Checkbox to 'Checked'

Tags: jquery, prop

I'm trying to set a checkbox to checked from an if statement but it just doesn't seem to want to work...

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="aircon" name="aircon" onchange="QuoteRefresh();" class="toggle"  />
```

and this is within my .js file:

```
$('#aircon').prop('checked', true);
```

I can't see any errors in the console.

Can anyone shed any light on this.

It's within a AJAX success response:

```
if (SelectedLevel == "Gold") {


  $('#aircon').prop('checked', true);

}
```

Can anyone help me??

This is what I'm getting within the console:

```
[input#aircon.toggle, context: document, selector: "#aircon", constructor: function, init:      function, selector: ""…]
0: input#aircon.toggle
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#aircon"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: Is this inside any event handler, some function? Do you have duplicate ids?

Comment: That works fine, show us the conditional and how it's triggered !

Comment: Yea it's within a if statement in a separate file...

Comment: Is it going inside the if condition which has this? do a console.log($('#aircon')) before this statement and see.

Comment: Is this happening during the page load? or are you doing it during some event handling etc?

Comment: post more code, or a fiddle, what you have isn't descriptive enough.

Comment: problem is you are not giving us enough information, we have no clue on what is happening.

Comment: try removing a few common sources of error : `if (SelectedLevel.trim().toLowerCase() == "gold") {...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: I'm trying to do it when the ajax response comes back successful...

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work, maybe your `QuoteRefresh();` method is returning false, or maybe your code handling the `checked` propertery isn't attached to the appropriate event that you want.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KAjPC/) of the `prop` method working.

#### edit (with information gathered from your initial comment on this answer)

If I'm understanding right, you're using the bootstrap toggle buttons component (which is represented with radio button values), and you're trying to change the actively toggled button with `.prop('checked', true);` but your components visual style isn't changing. This is because changing the `checked` property on a radio button from true to false or vice versa doesn't trigger any javascript events, which bootstrap relies on in order to update the visual state of the radio buttons.

Comment: I've just taken it out of the IF statement and it just doesn't seem to work... Could it be becuase I have styled the radio button into a toggle...

Comment: This is because of 'bootstrap-toggle-buttons' I've just added a fault on github.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect what I think your problem really is - You should consider editing your question to be more specific as to your problem.